# HDFS Java api: how to assign custom RPC port to each datanode

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to use Java API to access File on HDFS.

all namenode and datanode are behind firewall.

I only can access namenode and datanode using port mapping.

I mapped namenode:8020 to gateway:23541, datanode1:70010 to gateway:35621, datanode1:70020 to gateway:32514

I can set hdfs uri to hdfs://namenode:23541/tmp/my_file.txt

My question is how to assign custom RPC port to each datanode

Answer (score 0):

You can set `dfs.datanode.address` in `hdfs-site.xml` to define the bind address and port value.